# c++ GetPixel returning wrong values

Tags: c++, gdi

I am trying to make a program that can detect if the pixel I am looking for is black (if it has an RGB value of 0 0 0) and I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int isblack(int x, int y) {
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    unsigned int r = GetRValue(color);
    unsigned int g = GetGValue(color);
    unsigned int b = GetBValue(color);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    
    //Print the separate R G and B values of the pixel in position x, y
    std::cout << "red: " << r << "  ";
    std::cout << "green: " << g << "  ";
    std::cout << "blue: " << b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    //Print the x and y coordinates of where the mouse is pointing
    while (1) {
        POINT p;
        if (GetCursorPos(&p))
        {
            //cursor position now in p.x and p.y
            std::cout << p.x << "  " << p.y << "  ";
            //check if the pixel in p.x and p.y is black
            isblack(p.x, p.y);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am getting with this code is that it returns "wrong" RGB values. For example, if I hover over a clear white picture, the code does not return 255 255 255 as RGB but something seemingly random. When hovering over a black color, sometimes I get 0 0 0, sometimes 12 12 12, sometimes random values again.

I am guessing the problem has to do with HDC which is the only part of the code I don't really understand.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know why you're getting "random" values for "white" but 12 12 12 is awfully close to black.  Are you hovering over the screen looking at things that look "white" or "black" to you?  Or are you hovering over something that is _definitely_ white or black - e.g., a fully white or black image displayed in an image viewer?  The HDC stuff looks fine, standard Windows programming.  (I am assuming, of course, that you're on a "full color" 24 or 32 bit display surface ...)

Comment: Suggestion: Open a color picker dialog - go to the custom color picker - choose actual R G B values for the color you want (there are text input boxes there) - then hover over the little "sample" square and see what you're getting there.

Comment: While I know that some values come close to what they're supposed to be, they're actually not displaying correctly. I tried hovering the mouse over one area of the screen, got the RGB value 12,12,12. I took that same area and analyzed it with python and it returns 0 0 0 correctly. Color picker also returns 0 0 0.

Comment: Another weird thing about the script is that let's say I hover over a "black" ish color and the script returns 12 12 12, when I sometimes hover over a completely different color it still returns 12 12 12

Comment: OK.  Dunno then, sorry!

Comment: @Kian, Would you mind taking a screenshot of two colours that are different and both give (12,12,12)? Verify that it still happens when hovering over the screenshot after uploading the screenshot (just in case of colour conversions when it changes format) and then we can use that to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue (VS-2019/MSVC/Windows 10). However, when I set the display scale to 100% (I normally have it on 125%), then the problem goes away. But, even with the screen display set at 125%, your code appears to work when the cursor is within the console window.

Comment: @AdrianMole - wow!

Comment: @davidbak Was that a suggestion to try Windows-On-Windows emulation, or an expression of stunned admiration?

Comment: @AdrianMole - admiration of your investigation for sure! - but also dismayed astonishment that an API available since 16-bit Windows ruled the planet could be broken now (whether due to newer features in Windows itself or in device drivers coping with those newer features or whatever).

Comment: Found it! You need to call `SetProcessDPIAware();` at the beginning of your program (assuming Windows 10 and a non-100% scaled desktop). There's a duplicate ...